# extracting x and y data from a "messy" txt file

Tags: python, txt

I assume the question might be quite basic, but I had no idea how I should search for this specific issue:

I have a .txt file where over several lines, several x-y data points are present per line. x and y values that belong together are seperated by a comma, while the the different couples are seperated by space.

Here in example:
2,20 12,40 13,100 14,300
15,440 16,10 24,50 25,350
26,2322 27,3323 28,9999 29,2152
30,2622 31,50

I simply want to use python to store all x and y values in individual arrays. There must be an easy solution but I just cant get my head arround it how I should read them out.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

I tried to read out all line by themselfe and each line then value by value, but that is not working.

Comment: split by space to get `x,y` then split by comma to get `x` and `y`. Change data type as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileInp = "2,20 12,40 13,100 14,300 15,440 16,10 24,50 25,350 26,2322 27,3323 28,9999 29,2152 30,2622 31,50"

x = list()
y = list()

for data in fileInp.split():
    x_y_data = data.split(",")
    x.append(x_y_data[0])
    y.append(x_y_data[1])
   

print(x)
print(y)
```